# Parse complicated user input using Stream

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I am trying to figure out a way to parse the user input. There are commands that are one word, two words and three words long. Somehow I have to check now whether the user has entered an existing command and then pass on the arguments (all words after the command) - getArguments() does that for me.

How can I use Stream or anything else to find the entered command?

```
    String input = Terminal.readLine();
    final List<Command> commands = parser.initialiseCommands(register);
    final List<String> inputSplit = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
    final Command command = commands.stream()
          .filter(cmd -> cmd.getName().equals(???)
          .findAny()
          .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidInputException("no such command");
    final List<String> arguments = parser.getArguments(inputSplit, command);
    command.setArguments(arguments);
    command.execute();
```

initialiseCommands() holds all registered Commands. Every command has the getName() method which returns a String of the command name (e. g. for the add track command it's "add track").

Here are some commands of different length:

```
 - "add track <point> -> <point>" - length 2
 - "quit" - length 1
 - "delete rolling stock <id>" - length 3
 - "step <speed>" - length 1
```

Can someone please show me a way of how to do this? If any information is missing, please tell me. I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: Have you tried regex patterns?

Comment: I have but that didn't make it easier for me to distinguish between one-word, two-word and three-word commands.

Comment: Remove all `<word>` things, then split and count words?

Comment: What do you mean by `<word>` things?

Comment: Also, forget the stream for a minute. Focus on writing unit tests for each individual input

Comment: `<point>`, `<id>` `<speed>`

Comment: But how do you identify them? If the user types in "add track (1,2) -> (3,4)" - how do you know which belongs to the command and what the arguments are?

Comment: Do you have to make it so complicated? What about “start-track” or “starttrack” as commands instead so that they are easier to identify?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify what is a "command" and what is an "argument"?

Comment: What about `.filter(cmd -> input.startsWith(cmd.getName()))`?

Comment: @LorenzoAddazi That did the trick! Thank you very much!